# PHP extract each record in variable for insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, insert

Here is my PHP variable:

```
 $container = $_POST['containerNumber'];
```

Inside $_POST['containerNumber'], there are multiple container numbers that are retrieved when a user checks a checkbox from a form. That code is not necessary to display.  Just know that $_POST['containerNumber'] can have multiple container numbers assigned to it.

What I need to do is extract each container number from the POST so that I can run a mysql INSERT statement per each container number.

In the database table, there are multiple columns, with container_num being the column I'm trying to update (for now).

How can I turn $container into an array and retrieve each container number that has been assigned to the variable?

I know I need to utilize a FOREACH loop.  With that said, there will more than likely be multiple INSERT statements that will automatically be created with the loop.

```
 $SQL = "INSERT INTO myTable (container_num) VALUES ('$container')";
 // times however many containers the variable $container had stored in it
```

Please help.

EDIT **

Once the user checks however many checkboxes, I can display each container like this:

```
 <INPUT name="containerNumber" id="containerNumber" class="containerNumber" />
```

When I do this, it can be displayed to the screen like this:

```
 CONT_ID001, CONT_ID002, CONT_ID003...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please post a sample of the contents of `$container`. Is it already an array via a `[]` in the posting form? Is it delimited?

Comment: Edited my post. I do have javascript that appears to automatically separate each containerNumber with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

1) Give the POST parameters you're sending a name that ends with [], PHP automatically assigns them to an array when parsing the POST data. If you're sending the data from an HTML form, this is an example of how to do it:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>
        First container number:
        <input type="text" name="containerNumber[]" />
    </label>
    <label>
        Second container number:
        <input type="text" name="containerNumber[]" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" />
```

In PHP you can just do

```
foreach($_POST["containerNumber"] as $container) {
    ...
}
```

(Note that this is a feature of PHP and not portable to other server-side langages. This is NOT part of the HTTP specification.)

2) Separate values using some separator, in PHP use `explode()` to split it.

3) Send the form as JSON or encode that one field as JSON (if sent from HTML, I suggest using jQUery to do either option, as it's the easiest way) and use `json_decode()` in PHP to extract the contents.

4) Sevaral other options that may be suitable, depending on what exactly you're doing.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm looking at this correctly, but I don't think I can use multiple INPUT fields in my form for the containerNumber[]. But since I'm guessing containerNumber is already an array indicated by [], then the foreach loop should be able to distinguish each value in containerNumber. Is that right?

Comment: If you only got 1 input element, only 1 value is submitted. So you havwe to split that one. EIther client side using Javasdcript when sending the form and converting it into multiple valuies (send with the same name that endes with []), or server side (using explode() like suggested here and in Nelsons answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I get you, you have a $_POST variable with multiple values.

If the content of `$_POST['containerNumber']` is `CONT_ID001, CONT_ID002, CONT_ID003`

You can do this:

```
$result = preg_split("/, /", $_POST['containerNumber']);
//the result dump will be:
//$result[0] = "CONT_ID001";
//$result[1] = "CONT_ID002";
//$result[2] = "CONT_ID003";
```

The insert code should looks like to (assuming that you have one column for each number):

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO myTable ";
$columns = "";
$values = "";
foreach (result as $id=>$out){
    $columns .= "container_$id";
    $values .= "'$out'";
    if (count($result) < $id+1){
        $columns .= ", ";
        $values .= ", ";
    }
}
$SQL .= "($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

If you only have container_num column it should looks like:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO myTable (container_num) VALUES ('";
$columns = "";
$values = "";
foreach (result as $id=>$out){
    $values .= $out;
    if (count($result) < $id+1){
        $values .= ", ";
    }
}
$SQL .= "$values')";
```

Comment: No need for the (slow in comparison to less powerful functions) regular expression here. JUst use `explode(", ", $_POST['containerNumber'])`

Comment: So if I use this method, how would the INSERT statement look like? And would I need to utilize a FOREACH loop?

Comment: My program doesn't like the preg_split functionality. The pages no longer displays anything.

Comment: Nelson was missing a closing ) at the end of his statement  - that'S most likely why it deosn'T work for you. Also, yes, you have to use a foreach loop to get all the values, that statement just splits the one value that is submitted into an array. But most likely there are more elegant ways iuf you modify your query to insert multiple rows at once.